# No sound on Chromebook 11e converted from ChromeOS

Tags: drivers, sound, alsa, chromebook

Converted Chrome OS to Xubuntu 21.10 (tried 20.04) as well. All good but nod  sound.

Mixer only shows dummy output. Tried some tricks from here but no luck: [Fix No Sound (Dummy Output) Issue In Ubuntu With SND HDA Intel](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html)

### `dmesg` showing error:

```
[    6.040092] sof-audio-acpi-intel-byt 80860F28:00: error: tplg request firmware intel/sof-tplg/sof-byt-max98090.tplg failed err: -2
[    6.040100] sof-audio-acpi-intel-byt 80860F28:00: you may need to download the firmware from https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin/
```

### Hardware:

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 0e)
```

### APlay:

```
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: You may want to use this https://www.linuxium.com.au/isos instead of the standard Ubuntu installer.

Comment: The Lenovo ThinkPad 11e Chromebook cost $341.05 when it was released in 2015. Today it is worth twenty bucks? Last year I tried out a modern Chromebook and it had no problem running both ChromeOS and Ubuntu at the same time. Sometimes it's a question of how much your time is worth investing in archaic technology. Oh I took the liberty of cleaning up the formatting in your question. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Just wanted to mess around this old device and give my little girl, but no sound making it kinda useless. Thanks for making my question readable!

Comment: @BelindaFan The device is made for classrooms and designed for children. I hope someone with a similar device answers within 20 days to put a smile on a little girl's face at Xmas.

Comment: If nothing else works there are very cheap generic USB audio adapters that always work. As cheap as $1 will do.

Answer (score 0):

Try manually copying `sof-bin` firmware to `/lib/firmware/intel/sof-tplg/` folder. See instructions in the answer of [no sound due to error direct firmware load failed for intel/sof-tplg/sof-byt-max98090.tplg](https://askubuntu.com/q/1383051/581796)

*(I am not a developer, just a regular user who encountered a similar problem. )*